# A fully functional ASP.Net Core equivalent of Server.MapPath

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I'm looking for the ASP.Net Core (2.0) equivalent of System.Web's Server.MapPath.

The general advice for this is to use IHostingEnvironment's ContentRootPath with Path.Combine

e.g.

```
var fullPath = Path.Combine(_hostingEnvironment.ContentRootPath, localPath);
```

But if localPath may be a relative path (starting with '~'), that doesn't work. Or localPath might start with '/', or have no special prefix. If you look at the reference source for Server.MapPath (which seems to call Request.MapPath under the hood), it's a pretty complex beast, handling lots of scenarios. It uses another class VirtualPath, which in turn uses a UrlPath class. It sure doesn't just call Path.Combine.

So I'm wondering if something as functionally rich has made it into ASP.Net Core yet.

For the record, the reference source I was looking at for System.Web.HttpRequest was [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/System.Web/HttpRequest.cs).

Thanks

Comment: the tilde (`~`) just means relative to the applications root path. If you'd strip that out, it will most likely work (given that that path exists)

Comment: Thanks @Marco, but that's just one scenario I need to cope with... sometimes localPath will also start with a '/', sometimes without any special prefix. There's a lot of scenarios handled by System.Web's MapPath implementation, and I'm looking for something similarly robust. Might make that clearer in the question.

Comment: If it has a leading slash it will return a relative path and without a leading slash your code would return an absolute path. It will work in both cases. Do you have a specific problem or are you just looking for a all-in-one solution. If the latter is the case, I'm afraid, that stackoverflow is the wrong place for that kind of question.

Comment: We have a toolkit/framework for developing web apps across our enterprise. That toolkit can call this method with a range of different inputs - whilst I could list the scenarios that I currently know of, the question is really is is there an ASP.Net Core solution that offers the same level of robustness (i.e. handles the same number of scenarios) as the System.Web implementation of MapPath. That way I don't need to think about future scenarios, assuming that there's a good reason for the richness of the System.Web implementation. I hope you don't mind me asking that :)

Comment: My advise is: build an equivalent in .net Core and run all the unit tests you run against / with your toolkit. And if everything comes up green you are good to go. If not, you'd have a reason to ask it as a question here with a specific problem.

Comment: Yup, that looks like the way. I was just hoping that this was already done somewhere in .Net Core (in the interests of achieving parity with System.Web). Seems strange for me to have to rewrite a complex piece of System.Web, so i was asking if this was done already but lurking in an unknown place. 
But thanks for being the question police.

Comment: Ian of Oz - I'm interested, did you find a good solution to this?

Comment: @WillC, nothing better than I mentioned initially unfortunately - taking the reference source for System.Web as a base.